# Create Primary Key on SQL View

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, view

I am trying to bring a view of data into my Entity Framework model but its not showing up because the view does not had a primary key defined.

Sadly the database tables are made up from composite keys so there is no one column that I can use as a primary key. I have tried to create a combined key by concatinating the 3 columns together that make a row unique into a varchar column as shown below:

```
ISNULL(CAST(p.Id1 AS varchar(20)) + '-' + 
      CAST(p.Id2 AS varchar(20)) + '-' + 
      CAST(comp.id3 AS varchar(20)), 0) AS [SearchId]
```

I have then created a clustered index on this column as follows:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_Search ON [dbo].[Search] (SearchId)
```

But none of this has helped. It still doesn't show up in the Entity Framework Model and it still shows in SSMS as not being a PK.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Views don't have primary keys - you can create an **indexed view** by adding a clustering key - but you cannot define a primary key on a view - just cannot be done.

Comment: So what do I need to do to allow this View to come through into Entity Framework?

Comment: You need to define the pseudo "primary key" in the Entity Framework data model; you can do this manually by specifying the entity key property on those columns that should make up the "primary key" of your view, or if you don't do anything, the EF modelling tool will just use all non-nullable columns as "primary key" by default

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, I ended up not going down this route as I had to do some search functions in the database.  I ended up using a table valued function and that solved all my problems.